# Correct text direction on pdf file with c#

Tags: c#, pdf

I have pdf file that all the text come like that:

instead "hello my world" write "dlrow ym olleh"...

how can i convert the text to the correct please?

For example , the url

```
http://www.textreverse.com/
```

do it well,
I need to do it on c#

thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean change the pdf itself? Or extract the text and correct the reverse order? Or generate a pdf with correct order while now you somehow generate ones with reverse order? Or just reverse text without regard to the pdf? (that's what the link you provided does, as fas as I can see) Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse a string. Here is a way to do it:

**1.** Split your string to an array of chars:

```
char[] Chars = PdfString.ToCharArray();
```

**2.** Reverse the array:

```
Array.Reverse(Chars);
```

**3.** Convert a string out of this array:

```
string ReversedPdfString = new string(Chars);
```